# Clean up list of partial outputs for memory

Tags: memory, system

*Context*

I run long Mathematica sessions; sometimes I have Output up to Out[3000+]. Hence 
I would like to be able to clear out some previous outputs which do use lots of memory.

*Attempt*

I am aware of clearing some outputs via unprotecting `Out`  as follows

```
In[1]:= MemoryInUse[]/10^9.
```

Out[1]= 0.0179439

```
In[2]:= a = Table[1, {10^8}];
In[3]:= MemoryInUse[]/10^9.
```

Out[3]= 0.419424

```
In[4]:= Unprotect[Out];
In[5]:= Out[2] =.
In[6]:= Protect[Out];
In[7]:= MemoryInUse[]/10^9.
```

Out[7]= 0.0297147

My problem is if I have 3000+ outputs,  which one are using a lot of memory so I can decide if it is safe to clear them.

*Question*

What I am after is a way of finding out which amongst the previous `Out` are using most of the memory?
I would like to have a function, say `MemoryHog[n]`  which would return a list of numbers corresponding to the `n`th sorted Outputs using most memory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work

```
ClearAll[MemoryHog];
MemoryHog[n_] := Module[{list},
   list = {#, ByteCount[Out[#]]} & /@ Range[$Line];
   list=SortBy[list, -Last[#] &];
   list[[1 ;; n]]
];
```

Now lets test it

```
(*Some sample input -- evaluate in three cells *)
(*In[3]*)
Range[1000];
(*In[4]*)    
Range[10000];
(*In[5]*)    
Range[100000];

(*  get the hogs*)
MemoryHog[3]
(* ==>
{{5, 400168}, {4, 40168}, {3, 4168}}
*)
```

Comment: You remembered `$Line` before I did, but you seem to have forgotten about `SortBy`.

Comment: True, true, `list=SortBy[list, -Last[#] &]` would work as well...

Comment: Actually better; time it. :-)

Comment: Sorry, no time for that now :) I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @Ajasja I understand that `Instring/@ Transpose[MemoryHog[3]][[1]]` would allow me to review the corresponding Inputs. On the other hand its not very readable. Would you know how to print it out as the equivalent of `??In` but restricted to the hogs? It would help to decide if they can be cleared without pain.

Comment: As a quick hack this works `DisplayForm@ToExpression@InString[#] & /@ MemoryHog[3][[All, 1]]`

Answer (score 8):

Why do you have so many `Out[]` values assigned?  This seems like a very poor practice if memory is a concern.  I suggest setting something reasonable like `$HistoryLength = 3` and finding another way to store your results.

Nevertheless you can find the approximate memory used for each value like this:

```
Array[{#, ByteCount@Out@#} &, $Line - 1]
```

This gives output such as:

> ```
> {{1, 56}, {2, 184}, {3, 6520}}
> ```

which are a pairs: `{line-number, bytes-used}`

---

It is probably academic now that you know about `$HistoryLength`, but here is a way to write your "memory hog" function that has some features you may like.  It respects `$HistoryLength` and `$Line` such that it will not error if you request more `Out` values than are available, and it returns a `Short` summary of each `Out` value.

```
memoryHog[n_] :=
  Reverse@#[[# ~Ordering~ -Min[n, $HistoryLength, $Line - 1]]] & @ 
    Table[
      {ByteCount@Out@i, i, Short@Out@i},
      {i, Max[1, $Line - $HistoryLength], $Line - 1}
    ] // Column
```

Comment: @Wizard I have many Out[] because I do research ;-) i.e. I don't necessarily know where I am going. Or if you prefer I am not a good programmer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @chris That does not require you to keep *all* output, does it?  Perhaps you should look into a logging method that will write each `Out` to a file?

Comment: I didn't know about the $HistoryLength though. It might do the trick for me.

Comment: @Wizard No; typically I don't use any of the outputs.

Comment: @chris in that case, certainly set `$HistoryLength` to a low or zero value in your user  `init.m` file.  Ask if you need help with that.

Comment: @Wizard Thanks. Your version of memory hog assumes $HistoryLength is set it seems. I would be after input rather than output. I found that InString[5] gives me this input but in a strange format. I am sure you know how to make it human  readable ?

Comment: @chris sorry, yes this assumes that `$HistoryLength` is set, but I forgot to state it explicitly.  Try: `DisplayForm @ ToExpression @ InString[5]`

Comment: Thanks; I ll modify your function accordingly. The problem I see with the current form is that Short[ something big] takes a while to process.

Comment: @chris if the input line is descriptive enough you could use `DisplayForm @ ToExpression @ InString @ i` in the place of `Short @ Out @ i` -- perhaps you already are doing this.