# Identify which cell uses most memory in front-end

Tags: graphics, front-end

Even though the mathematica front-end is much more robust than it used to be, 
everyone must have noticed that when a few 3D graphics are involved, the front-end produces very large notebooks which are more difficult to manage.

I am aware of the option to rasterise 3D plots using Image

```
 Plot3D[Sin[1/x 1/y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},PlotPoints -> 200]//Image[#,ImageResolution-> 300]&
```

which produces a file of 1.2 MB versus one of 11 MB (without the Image).

I am looking for a method to identify within a given notebook which graphics outputs
use most memory on the front-end (and potentially disc space when the notebook is saved), in order to rasterize these outputs. 
Ideally I would rather not rasterize all plots as the interactivity is useful.

Note that this question differs from [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6157/5)  about identifying which
outputs use most kernel memory when stored in Out[] variables.

**Question**

1. How to identify which cells use most memory on the front-end in a given notebook?
2. Possibly automate the process of rasterising those cells?

May be there is a front end setup to tell it to not produce interactive plots?

Comment: Isn't this similar to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9634/5) of yours? Also relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6157/5

Comment: @rm I did not forget this question ;-) The previous question was about kernel memory. This time I am concerned with Front-end memory (actually file size). Should I edit my question to reflect this difference?

Comment: Yes, editing to clarify would be nice :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Brett has just posted something along the lines of what I was thinking. I had a look at the code for the cell statistics and it uses `CurrentValue` so a manual approach would be to evaluate:

```
Dynamic@CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "ByteCount"]
```

and then click on a cell bracket and observe the byte count. This can probably be automated using `SelectionMove` to step through the cells and record the byte count.

[image]

**Edit**

Using `SelectionMove` (I added a pause just to watch it working)

```
x = {};
Do[SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]; 
  x = {x, First@CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "ByteCount"]}; 
  Pause[0.5], {15}];
Flatten[x]

(* {932, 7258, 992, 1039, 2150, 35190, 2121, 992, 2584, 9408, 1016, \
1791, 1529, 1657, 2775} *)
```

In principle you can also record the cell label and thereby identify which cell has large byte counts. For some reason this was not working for me and i haven't been able to figure out what the problem is. It works fine in the documentation notebook:

[image]

However when I cut and paste the code into a notebook and evaluate it doesn't work:

[image]

So if someone can explain why I am failing to obtain a cell label then the `Do` loop above can be modified to record the cell label and corresponding byte count.

**Edit #2**

restarted Mma and now this is working, so starting from the bottom of your notebook (selecting 15 cells in this example):

```
x = {};
nb=EvaluationNotebook[];
Do[SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]; 
  x = {x, {Options[NotebookSelection[nb], CellLabel][[-1, 2]], 
     First@CurrentValue[nb, "ByteCount"]}}; 
  Pause[0.5], {15}];
Partition[Flatten[x], 2]

(* {{"Out[122]=", 14811}, {"In[123]:=", 10149}, {"Out[93]=", 
  3490}, {"In[91]:=", 7127}, {None, 992}, {"Out[90]=", 
  1006}, {"In[90]:=", 2134}, {"Out[89]=", 35008}, {"In[89]:=", 
  2071}, {None, 992}, {"In[87]:=", 2543}, {"Out[86]=", 
  9259}, {"In[86]:=", 1015}, {"In[85]:=", 1785}, {"In[84]:=", 1515}} *)
```

or for a big notebook limit the output to byte counts above a certain level

```
Cases[Partition[Flatten[x], 2], {_, x_ /; x > 10000}]
(* {{"Out[122]=", 14811}, {"In[123]:=", 10149}, {"Out[89]=", 35008}} *)
```

**Edit #3**

In response to @Chris conversation

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
Do[
  SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
  tmp = First@CurrentValue[nb, "ByteCount"];
  If[tmp > 10000, 
   SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], CellDingbat -> "Big"]];,
  {15}];
```

Comment: What do the two values mean?

Comment: total bytes and content bytes, as per Brett's screen grab.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks! As you point out this solution fails when the notebook is fresh: may be one could add a tag on large cells as is done in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/customize-front-end-to-add-notifications-when-evaluation-finishes?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch just as a note, you need to do something like nb = Notebooks[][[1]]; so that your code works (?).

Comment: yes sorry. `nb=EvaluationNotebook[]` was what I used.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I have slightly modified your solution via the function `CellMemory[]:=CreatePalette[Framed[Panel[Dynamic@CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "ByteCount"][[1]]]],
                             WindowTitle -> "Cell Memory" ];`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch on the other hand, I also fail to get correctly the In[..]= statements from your second edit solution.

Comment: @Chris maybe you are experiencing the same problem i had during the first edit. I couldn't identify the cause but when i restarted the cell labels were recorded ok.

Comment: @Chris it looks like you were having a conversation about setting cell dingbats. I'll make an edit that shows how to do that.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch; Thanks a lot; I 've edited it to a function `CellMemoryTag[memorymax_: 100000, tag_: "\[WarningSign]"] :=
 Module[{nb = EvaluationNotebook[]},
  Do[SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
    tmp = First@CurrentValue[nb, "ByteCount"];
    If[tmp > memorymax, 
     SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], 
      CellDingbat -> tag]];, {$Line}];]`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a manual process:

- Bring up the **Notebook History...** dialog (located in the **Cells** menu)
- Set the history to **Selected Cells**
- Open the **Cell
  Statistics** section
- Select a cell, and read the value out of the
  table:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use `NotebookGet` to access the underlying Notebook expression and then process it.  Use `Notebooks[]` to find an open Notebook, or `NotebookOpen` to open one, and assign the NotebookObject to `nb`.  In a new window:

```
Notebooks[]
nb = %[[3]];
```

Then we can print all cells that take over 1MB of storage:

```
Cases[NotebookGet[nb], 
  x : Cell[__, "Output"] /; ByteCount[x] > 1*^6 :> CellPrint@x, -1];
```

This doesn't help you locate the cells but it does identify them.

You could also print corresponding Input cells if that makes localization easier:

```
Cases[NotebookGet[nb], 
 x : CellGroupData[{Cell[__, "Input"], __}, __] /; 
   ByteCount[x] > 1*^6 :> CellPrint@Cell@x, -1]
```

Comment: similar to my attempt above, **if** the cell labels are retained in the notebook then you could extract the cell label, `Cell[__, "Output",___,Rule["CellLabel",z_],___]` and produce {z,byte count}

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am sorry I don't seem to be able to make this solution work. It returns {}.

Comment: @chris are you sure you have a valid NotebookObject?  Do you understand that part 3 (`[[3]]`) is just an example?  What do you get for `Length @ NotebookGet @ nb` and `ByteCount @ NotebookGet @ nb`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am sure. I get In[29]:= Length@NotebookGet@nb 
 ByteCount@NotebookGet@nb
Out[29]= 5
Out[30]= 97520

Comment: @chris okay, in that case you have a valid NotebookObject but there are no large graphics in the referenced Notebook: the entire file is only 97kb.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard but shouldn't `Cases[NotebookGet[nb], 
 x : CellGroupData[{Cell[__, "Output"], __}, __] /; 
   ByteCount[x] > 1*^1 :> CellPrint@Cell@x, -1]` return something?

Comment: @chris you seem to be blending my two methods; The `CellGroupData` pattern should use `"Input"` or be reformulated as `CellGroupData[{__, Cell[__, "Output"], ___}, __]` (perhaps; not tested).

Comment: If I cut and paste your code above `Cases[NotebookGet[nb], 
  x : Cell[__, "Output"] /; ByteCount[x] > 1 :> CellPrint@x, -1];` just replacing 1*^6 by 1 It returns `{}` When I run it on a large notebook containing many figures it does the same. May be I am being dumb. Just wanted to let you know that at least one person fails to run that code correctly ;-)

Comment: @chris That is unanticipated.  Maybe there is something different in version 8 than version 7 (which I use) or I'm forgetting the syntax of `Cell`.  On a whim what happens with `Cases[NotebookGet[nb], x : Cell[__, "Output", ___] :> CellPrint@x, -1]` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5969/discussion-between-chris-and-mr-wizard)