# Forget past outputs to free memory

Tags: memory, kernel

While tinkering with a notebook that loads a large chunk of data in memory, I noticed that if I run it multiple times, the past chunks reside in memory. I understand that the reason (or one of) for which this happens is that the past output mechanism (`%`) keeps a reference to them, so they cannot be garbage collected.

Is there a way to explicitly make *Mathematica* forget some data?

Comment: You can set `$HistoryLength = 0` for instance.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9634/clean-up-list-of-partial-outputs-for-memory

Comment: See [common pitfalls / $HistoryLength](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80978/4999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
 $HistoryLength = k
```

to keep the last `k` lines of input and output.