# How to know each variable used how much RAM

Tags: memory

Is it possible to know what percentage of total used RAM by MMA is used by individual variables? I want to know how the total used RAM is distributed among different variables. `Bytecount` gives the answer but I have to enter the name of each variable manually.

Comment: Somewhat related: [(9634)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9634/121),

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 1000}];
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 10000}];
Column@Thread@{Names["Global`*"], ByteCount[#] & /@ ToExpression /@ Names["Global`*"]}
```

> ```
> {"a", 8000152}
> {"b", 800000152}
> ```

It will show you all user-defined expressions and some of components of `Global` context created by default.

Comment: I use MMA 9. Executing the code returns nothing. I think this is because I set the notebook's context as `Unique to this notebook`

Comment: I've checked this namelly with MMA9. Did you run it on an empty kernel?
Try to create any expression before..

Comment: It works if the notebook's context is set to Global. If the context is unique to the notebook it won't work.

Comment: Yes, :) because the list of variables is taken from the Global context. You can replace the name of context to your current.
Or use this `Names[$Context<>"*"]` as recommend Alexey Popkov in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166027/list-all-user-defined-variables-functions-in-a-notebook-in-mathematica

Comment: @Öskå Yes, you're right. I think without `ToExpression` it returns the memory used by the string not the actual variable.

Comment: It does not work with ToExpression :\ as I see

P.S. I found the misprint, It works good

Comment: This works good for me:

`Table[{Names[$Context <> "*"], ByteCount[#] & /@ ToExpression /@ Names[$Context <> "*"]}, {i, 1,1}];`

Comment: @Öskå. Alright.

Then, I can use `SortBy[Flatten[tt, 1]\[Transpose], Last]` to get the used memory by increasing order. `tt` is the code in my last comment.

Comment: @Öskå. If I add the total amount of used RAM by the code I wrote, the result is not equal to `MemoryInUse[]`. Do you know why?

Comment: @yashar I guess the frontend takes memory too, plus many other services. See `MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd]`

Comment: The `ByteCount[#] & /@ ToExpression /@ Names[$Context <> "*"]` shows some additional service expressions in case if you have dynamic output in your notebook. So, the total amount of used memory could be bigger than sum of user-defined expressions consumption.