# Clear a symbol from the kernel

Tags: clear

I have a code that works over lists like

```
S0; (*initial list*)
S1=f[S0];
S2=g[S1];
S3=f[S2];
S4=f[S3];
.
.
.
```

where `f` and `g` are functions that produces larger lists that consume a large amount of RAM memory. I thought that running

```
S0; (*initial list*)
S1=f[S0]; Clear[S0];
S2=g[S1]; Clear[S1];
S3=f[S2]; Clear[S2];
S4=f[S3]; Clear[S3];
.
.
.
```

would free the memory used from the kernel, but it is not the case. The consumption of both codes are exactly the same. I stored (using `Save`) the result for S10, for example, and after `Get` it (with a clear kernel) the memory consumption is much less than running the code, even using `Clear` in each step as above.

Is there a stronger version of `Clear` which eliminates the information of a symbol from the kernel? Or does `Clear` do it, but the task manager keeps showing the same memory usage from before?

Comment: One thing to try is `$HistoryLength` -- change it to something much less than the default.

Comment: @bills Can I redefine `$HistoryLength` later? Like, if I aim to get `S10` and then make other operations using it and other things, can I redefine to infinity after the computation of `S10`?

Comment: @bills And it removes lines from the beginning? Is is possible to keep some definitions before start the string of calculations in the OP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @bills says, you can just set `$HistoryLength=0`, but that's rather draconian. Instead, just make sure that [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out) doesn't store your results. To do this, you need to use something like:

```
S0; "";
```

instead of something like:

```
S0; Null;
```

Let's compare the two:

```
S0; "";
S1 = f[S0]; ""; Clear[S0];
S2 = g[S1]; ""; Clear[S1];

DownValues[Out][[-3;;]]
```

> {HoldPattern[%56] :> "", HoldPattern[%57] :> "", HoldPattern[%58] :> ""}

versus your:

```
S0;
S1 = f[S0]; Clear[S0];
S2 = g[S1]; Clear[S1];

DownValues[Out][[-3;;]]
```

> {HoldPattern[%60] :> S0, HoldPattern[%61] :> f[S0], 
>    HoldPattern[%62] :> g[f[S0]]}

Notice how the "" version doesn't store any outputs, while your version does. It is the storage of the outputs that prevents you from recovering memory.

**Update**

A more normal method to avoid memory bloat is to use a [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module). For example:

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := x+1

func[s_] := Module[{res = s},
    res = f[res];
    res = g[res];
    res = f[res];
    res = f[res];
    Total[res]
]
```

Now, create a large variable:

```
MemoryInUse[]
S0 = RandomReal[1,10^8];"";
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 151355496
>
> 951357168

Note the use of `;"";` above so that `Out` doesn't store the value of `S0`. Run your function:

```
MemoryInUse[]
func[S0]
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 951358872
>
> 4.21584*10^8
>
> 951359968

Notice that [`MemoryInUse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemoryInUse) has stayed basically the same.

Finally, clear `S0` and recover memory:

```
MemoryInUse[]
Clear[S0]
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 951651720
>
> 151652648

If we hadn't used `;"";` above, the memory wouldn't have gone down.

Comment: `MemoryInUse[]` is showing the same amount (about 500mb in my test) in both cases, `""` or `Clear`. What happened?

Comment: If those symbols are already in Out, then doing the above won't help. You could look at [Clean up list of partial outputs for memory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9634/45431) and see if the answers there help. Or you could restart your kernel.

Comment: Hey man, after that edit, I think your code did the trick :D Why???

Comment: Because my original code prevented S1, S2, etc. from being stored in Out, but I hadn't cleared them, so their values still had to be stored in memory.

Comment: Does it makes any difference if I put `;""; Clear[?];` in each line inside `Module`?

Comment: You don't need to worry about Out inside a Module, so there is no need for that.