# Finding the best way to try `Parallelize` a code

Tags: parallelization, memory

Consider a code like

```
S0; (*initial list*)
S1=f[S0]; ""; Clear[S0];
S2=g[S1]; ""; Clear[S1];
S3=f[S2]; ""; Clear[S2];
S4=f[S3]; ""; Clear[S3];
S5=f[S4]; ""; Clear[S4];
S6=g[S5]; ""; Clear[S5];
S7=f[S6]; ""; Clear[S6];
S8=f[S7]; ""; Clear[S7];
```

where there is a considerable usage of RAM memory and processing in each evaluation of the functions. **I have two questions.** The first question is whether there is any difference between

```
S0; (*initial list*)
Parallelize[S1=f[S0]; ""; Clear[S0];]
Parallelize[S2=g[S1]; ""; Clear[S1];]
Parallelize[S3=f[S2]; ""; Clear[S2];]
Parallelize[S4=f[S3]; ""; Clear[S3];]
Parallelize[S5=f[S4]; ""; Clear[S4];]
Parallelize[S6=g[S5]; ""; Clear[S5];]
Parallelize[S7=f[S6]; ""; Clear[S6];]
Parallelize[S8=f[S7]; ""; Clear[S7];]
```

and

```
S0; (*initial list*)
Parallelize[S1=f[S0]; ""; Clear[S0];
S2=g[S1]; ""; Clear[S1];
S3=f[S2]; ""; Clear[S2];
S4=f[S3]; ""; Clear[S3];
S5=f[S4]; ""; Clear[S4];
S6=g[S5]; ""; Clear[S5];
S7=f[S6]; ""; Clear[S6];
S8=f[S7]; ""; Clear[S7];]
```

The second question is whether, maybe [within this list](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html), `Parallelize` is the best option for the code to try run in parallel in a supercomputer.

Comment: Seems like your outermost code structure is a fold. You could reformulate it with `Fold[]` but because of the sequential dependency this wouldn't offer much opportunities for parallelization. So the only possible gain for parallelization can probably only happen inside your `f`/`g` calls. Which means there's probably not much difference between a big `Parallelize` or many small ones in your example. If you give a bit more details how your `f`/`g` function looks like it might be easier to say how this can be optimized. I would start with the `Fold` refactoring.

Comment: This eliminates the need for intermediate results and `Clear` (otherwise use `FoldList` if you want those). Also two more things. The `"";` in your code currently does nothing, is there a reason why you write it like this? And traditionally, capitalized definitions are used for function definitions. Using them for variables can lead to problems when the name collides with internal functions (like `N`).

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke The answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157156/52401 explains why using `"";`Actually the repetition in the OP are automatically made with a `Module` (and then it doesn't makes difference to use  `""; Clear[?]`). My first question is just whether there is any different to `Parallelize` evaluations individually or pieces of code.